# Is it possible to measure performance other than testing speed of execution?

Tags: java, sockets, testng

I have a simple protocol which tries for example file transfer from one PC to other. I have a test which utilizes "virtual UDP path" and two clients. Test tries to send given file from one instance to the other. Instances talk to each other through "virtual UDP path" which I have implemented instead of UDP Sockets (which are used in real world) by using two blocking queues.

Now I want to start monitoring regressions by monitoring transferred data through my virtual UDP path. Also I want to simulate packet loss and lag in network by some process in virtual UDP path implementation.

Is it possible to monitor any other thing than execution speed performance of some test? I want to monitor custom performance value of test. It will be for example amount of transferred bytes to complete a given test. I want to report the given custom performance values at end of the given test. Is it possible with testing and if yes, how?

I want it to monitor in a such way which is natural for testng framework. So for example to have these custom performance related values in output xml file (testng-results.xml) and possibly to have visualized them in jenkins through performance plugin.

Answer (score 0):

short answer:
yes

long answer:
performance always relates to something else,
it could be speed performance or memory performance.
In Java is a little bit tricky to know the exact memory allocation because you don't explicitly allocate memory space